# PostgreSQL event trigger to force extension installations into particular schema

Tags: postgresql, trigger, ddl, dml, ddl-trigger

I have a dedicated schema `extensions` (PostgreSQL v 9.6.3) where I intend to install all extensions for my DB. I would like to somehow disallow (or at least remind) users installing extensions without specify particular schema.

So this should fail

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

but this should succeed:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc SCHEMA extensions;
```

For this purpose, I tried creating event trigger:

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER e010_verify_extension_schema_et
  ON ddl_command_end
  WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE EXTENSION')
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE verify_extension_schema();
```

and in `verify_extension_schema()` function I am trying to make use of `pg_catalog.pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()`.
However, the function does not return anything I can use to check if schema has been specified or which schema for that matter...

Does anyone have any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Is it the specification you want, or the installation into `public`? IE, should a manual install into public be allowed, `CREATE EXTENSION x SCHEMA public`?

Comment: Would like to force all extensions to install using dedicated schema `extensions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're using `ddl_command_end`, it can still fail or remind users which is what you want. [From the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-definition.html),

> Similarly, if a **`ddl_command_end` trigger fails with an error, the effects of the DDL statement will be rolled back**, just as they would be in any other case where the containing transaction aborts.

Unfortunately, you have two options after that

1. Process it possibly making assumptions, but only *knowing* the place in which the extension was installed. For instance, `CREATE EXTENSION x WITH SCHEMA CURRENT_SCHEMA` and `CREATE EXTENSION x` will be conflated. Simple access to the command executed isn't available because some simple commands issue multiple commands (ex, `serial` being a macro).
2. Process the internal [`pg_ddl_command`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-event-triggers.html) with a C function.

Because the second option sounds like less joy, let's go with the first.

Check out the list under [Capturing Changes at Command End](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-event-triggers.html) which supports `objid` being returned from the SRF `pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()`. **Note, `schema_name` is not what you're after**.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verify_extension_schema()
RETURNS event_trigger
AS $$
DECLARE
  schemafail bool;
BEGIN
  schemafail = (
    SELECT n.nspname = 'public'
    FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() AS ev
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_extension AS e
      ON ev.objid = e.oid
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS n
      ON e.extnamespace = n.oid
  );
  IF schemafail THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Creating extensions into "public" is disabled';
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER nag_my_users
  ON ddl_command_end
  WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE EXTENSION')
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE verify_extension_schema();
```

Now you can

```
test=# CREATE EXTENSION intarray ;
ERROR:  Creating extensions into "public" is disabled
test=# CREATE EXTENSION intarray WITH SCHEMA public;
ERROR:  Creating extensions into "public" is disabled
test=# CREATE EXTENSION intarray WITH SCHEMA foo;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

If you just want a notification, you can change it to `RAISE NOTICE`

Comment: so the trick is not to parse SQL looking for schema, but to inspect the catalog to see where extension installed and cause rollback if it is in unwanted schema ?

Comment: That is correct. Unless you know C and want to write it in C